# Fragment in Actionbar Tab and ViewPager

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, android-actionbar, android-viewpager

Is it possible to use a Fragment in both tablet Actionbar Tabs and phone ViewPager?  It appears that the phone uses the support library and that isn't compatible with the TabListener in the Actionbar.  Is there a trick to getting both to use the same Fragment?

The only possible workaround I've seen so far is [this](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/).

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, check out the `ActionBarTabsPager` sample in the compatibility library source. You need to implement both interfaces in your adapter to handle tab switching and paging. Something like this:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, ActionBar.TabListener {
        // implement both
}
```

You need to add tabs like this (using the support/compatibility library):

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.content);
tabsAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportActionBar(),
                viewPager);
ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
tabsAdapter.addTab(tab, f);
```

Comment: This is nice, but the tabs are not on the Actionbar on the tablet.

Comment: Naturally, you need to use the ActionBar APIs to add the tabs. See revised post. This is from a real project, so I am pretty sure it works :).

Comment: -san!  Omoshiroi!.  Since your first answer something about your name struck me...as I read your second response today, my tablet notifies me that I have an upgrade for an installed app.  Lo and behold...WWWJDIC.  :-)  ...and the TabPager works really well in there, too!  I also, have Kanji Recognizer installed.  Thank you for your help and for your apps!

Comment: getSupportActionBar() is in ActionBarSherlock lib not in compatibility library ...

Comment: Anyone looking for complete solution should try this (you should have ADT v20 and up) - Menu > Project > Select Android Application Project + fill project properties and select min-sdk to API 14 > Click Next > [optional] create your launcher icon > Click Next > Check "Create Activity" and select "BlankActivity" > Click Next > Select navigation type to "Tabs + Swipe" > Click Finish. Done, you have a working example with tab + viewpager

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html

This is the good way to use Fragment from compatibility library with ActionBar.Tab and TabListener.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example implementation of TabsPagerAdapter https://wwwjdic.googlecode.com/svn-history/r684/branches/2.0/wwwjdic/src/org/nick/wwwjdic/TabsPagerAdapter.java from Nikolay Elenkov answer.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use android-support-v13.jar. This file includes FragmentPagerAdapter for native fragments as well as ViewPager.